# Visual Studio has exited with code 0 using LibQxt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, libqxt

I'm trying to use the LibQxt extension within my Qt project in Visual Studio 2010. However, everything is working till i start the application. In the place where i use the first Qxt-object (does not matter which, "QxtSpanSlider * slider = new QxtSpanSlider()" or just "QxtSpanSlider slider;" for example) the program exits with code 0. What could be the problem when a program using a library "crashes" like this without any error?

I compiled Qxt using mscv2010.

Answer (score 0):

No then you get an error while starting the application.

The problem was that i tried to use release build library in debug mode. Compiling Qxt again in Debug mode did make it work.